# Text lables are misplaced on the dodged bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to show the `mean` values on the bargraph. But they are somehow misplaced. Any help?

```r
library(pacman)
#> Warning: package 'pacman' was built under R version 4.2.1
p_load(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy, fill = fl)) +
  geom_bar(stat ='identity', position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(geom = "text", 
               stat = mean,
               aes(label = after_stat(round(..y.., 2))))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: stat
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You can add `position = position_dodge(0.9)` to the summary layer.

Comment: @teunbrand I would like to display the numbers above the bars.

Comment: You can play with the `vjust` in the summary/text layer to nudge the text a bit.